# Converting Actionscript 2.0 to Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm not really good at doing actionscript and I have some trouble making and converting AS 2.0 to AS 3.0... is there an easy way to convert this AS 2.0 code

```
for(var n=8; n<50; n++)
{
    var spinner:MovieClip = spinner.duplicateMovieClip("bluebit"+n, n);
    bluebit._rotation = Math.random()*360;
    bluebit._alpha = Math.floor(Math.random()*30)+80;
    bluebit._xscale = Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+60;
    bluebit._yscale = Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+60;
    bluebit.gotoAndPlay(Math.random()*5);
}
```

to AS 3.0?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the most part [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html%22this%22) should tell you everything you need to know about your conversion of the program.

Comment: And this is exactly why link only answers aren't advised :-(